# Ubuntu SDK Freeze on deployment

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk

When building an ubuntu phone qml app on the ubuntu sdk, the sdk freezes on 'deployment'. I can't interact with the sdk. The 'kill' command isn't working. The issue does not occur when building and running the app as an desktop app.

My current problem is getting to the core of the problem. I don't know where to look for the logs (in case there are any). Has anyone experienced the same issue?

My setup:

- Ubuntu 14.04 System
- Ubuntu SDK / QT-Creator (3.1.1)
- Ubuntu sdk 15.04 arm Kit
- Aquaris BQ 4.5

Thanks for any answers in advance.
Peter

**Edit**:

- The error occurs, when connection to the phone. I can reproduce the problem on clicking 'test' in the device section of the ubuntu-sdk settings.
- Also connecting to an i386 emulator results in a system freeze.

Does anyone know how to an app manually as a workaround?

Comment: Copy through ssh and install with `click` command. For the freeze problem: check that ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa is set; maybe look into syslog when it freezes.

Answer (score 1):

After several hours I decided to follow the pragmatic path and reinstall my laptop with Ubuntu 15.04. Everything works fine now and I'm able to deploy my apps to my phone.